# Redirect https:// to https://www

Tags: nginx, https, url-rewriting, forge

I have a ubuntu server with DigitalOcean which is managed using forge.laravel.com

I have tried numerous different methods in the nginx.conf file to redirect all the possible scenarios to my domain https://www.domain.com

```
https://www.domain.com = https://www.domain.com -- GREAT
http://domain.com = https://www.domain.com -- GREAT
http://www.domain.com = https://www.domain.com -- GREAT
https://domain.com = https://domain.com -- This should redirect to the www.
```

**heres part of my nginx.conf**

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        server_name domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri; 
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain.com;
        root /home/forge/default/public;

.... other nginx.conf configuration
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried numerous combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri; 
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/forge/default/public;
```

By

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri; 
    #INSERT HERE CERTIFICATES DIRECTIVES

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /home/forge/default/public;
```